# Rails has many through select2 drop down param problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, strong-parameters

I have a select2 select field that I am choosing option types attached to a product. I have a has many though relationship between products and option_types through product_option_types. I am trying to take the comma delimited select2 result and create the join table records for preoduct_option_types. So far it is not working though.

I am getting an error unknown attribute 'option_type_id' for Product. Below are the details. Any thoughts on how to do this?

product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_one_attached :main_image, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :product_option_types, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :option_types, through: :product_option_types


  has_many :variants, inverse_of: :product

end
```

option_types model:

```
class OptionType < ApplicationRecord
  with_options dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :option_type do
    has_many :option_values, -> { order(:position) }
    has_many :product_option_types
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :products, through: :product_option_types
end
```

product_option_types model:

```
class ProductOptionType < ApplicationRecord
  with_options inverse_of: :product_option_types do
      belongs_to :product
      belongs_to :option_type
  end

  validates :product, :option_type, presence: true
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: { scope: :option_type_id }, allow_nil: true
end
```

product _form

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">

  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :stock %>
    <%= form.text_field :stock, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :available_on %>
    <%= form.text_field :available_on, class: 'form-control', data: { behavior: "flatpickr" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :price %>
    <%= form.text_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label 'Category' %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories, u/product.category_id), class: 'form-control', :prompt => 'Select category') %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" data-controller='select2'>
    <%= form.label :option_type_id %>

    <%= form.select :option_type_id, OptionType.all.map { |type| type.presentation }, {include_blank: false}, class: 'form-control content-search', multiple: 'multiple' %>

  </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <% if product.persisted? %>
    <div class="float-right">
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, class: "text-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </div>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", product, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", products_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label 'Main Product Image' %>
    <%= form.file_field :main_image, classs: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <% if product.persisted? %>

      <div class="form-group">
          <%= link_to "Manage Variants", product_variants_path(@product), class: "btn btn-link" %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

product controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_data
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    u/products = Product.all
    u/option_types = OptionType.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    puts params.inspect
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    u/product = Product.new
    u/product.option_types.new
    u/categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
    u/variants = Variant.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    u/categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
    u/option_types = u/product.option_types
    u/product.option_types.new
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    u/product = Product.new(product_params)
    u/product.user_id = current_user.id
    u/product.category_id = params[:category_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if u/product.save
        format.html { redirect_to u/product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: u/product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: u/product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    u/product.category_id = params[:category_id]

    if u/product.option_types.present?
      u/product.option_types = u/product.option_types.split(',')
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if u/product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to u/product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: u/product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: u/product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    u/product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      u/product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def load_data
      u/option_types = OptionType.order(:name)
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :stock, :available_on, :price, :user_id, :main_image, :option_type_ids, :option_type_id: [])
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was not passing the id through in the select field. I changed it to this and it is working.

```
  <%= form.select :option_type_ids, OptionType.all.map { |type| [type.presentation, type.id] }, {prompt: true}, class: 'form-control content-search', multiple: 'multiple' %>
```